# jQuery variable inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm learning JS and jQuery and this one I just don't understand.
I'm creating new element using jQuery and I want to use for loop to make 5 of them.

```
var $daisy =  $("<img>")
.attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/English_Daisy_(Bellis_Perennis).jpg")
.attr("width", "35")
.attr("alt","Daisy Photo")
.appendTo("body");
```

if I paste this code inside for loop it'll work and I'll have 5 of them side by side, but it doesn't work when I just type variable there:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      $daisy;
       }
```

can anyone please explain me why it doesn't work with var name but it works when I paste all code? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because when you are using the variable, you have only executed the `appendTo` once.

The way jQuery generally works, is by chaining commands.  A selector/creator selects or creates DOM elements and returns the object, which is acted upon by additional functions using dot notation `.`, and so on until there are no more functions in the chain and the final object is returned.  This can be stored to a variable.  You are not storing the functions in a variable, you are storing the result of the functions.  In your case, you are appending the new `img` to the `body` and the result (the object) is returned and stored in the variable.

When you put that variable in a loop, nothing happens, because it is just a value, not a function.

Your code:

```
var $daisy = $("<img>")  // create an img element and return it
.attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/English_Daisy_(Bellis_Perennis).jpg") // assign the src value, return the img element
.attr("width", "35")  // modify the width, return the img element
.attr("alt","Daisy Photo") // add an alt attribute, return the img element
.appendTo("body"); // add the img element to the body, AND RETURN IT, storing in $daisy
```

So `$daisy` now contains, in essence: `<img src="url" alt="Daisy Photo" style="width: 35">`, which has also been added to `body`.  The `appendTo` is complete at this point.

When you put all of the code in the loop, you create and append it every time.

You could, however, do this:

```
var $daisy = $("<img>")
.attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/English_Daisy_(Bellis_Perennis).jpg")
.attr("width", "35") 
.attr("alt","Daisy Photo");

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $daisy.clone().appendTo("body");
}
```

Note, you do need to use `clone()` in this case, otherwise jQuery will remove the original `img` from its DOM location and append it again, resulting in a single `img` still.  Cloning makes a copy to append.

Comment: wow, now I get it. I thought it had something to do with `appendTo`, I tried changing it in `for ` loop but didn't know exactly to what. Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function:

```
function daisy(){  
    $("<img>")
    .attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/English_Daisy_(Bellis_Perennis).jpg")
    .attr("width", "35")
    .attr("alt","Daisy Photo")
    .appendTo("body");
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    daisy();
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! so it's down to me not realizing that variable is just a value and I had to use function or use `clone()`